# PHP "if" not working

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

I have a Table where i want to Display time someone has worked. This comes from a mySql a Field should Display the minutes, and if a other field ist true, then it should be add "high" after the minutes

I tried this:

```
Print "<td width=50px>";
PRINT $info['minutes'] if($info['high'] == 0 ) {echo "Hoch"} ;
```

and got this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\callinfo.php on line 63
```

Someone can Help? :)

Comment: Missing semi-colon, case issues...

Answer (score 2):

You need to space out your code if you can't handle parse errors. Also, print/echo are pretty much same, use one or the other, not both, make your life easier in the future when you're looking for specific code.

```
PRINT $info['minutes'];
if ( $info['high'] == 0 ) {
    echo "Hoch";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `;`

```
PRINT $info['minutes'] ;
if($info['high'] == 0 )
{
   echo "Hoch";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It lacks a **;** after **PRINT $info['minutes']**

```
PRINT $info['minutes'];
```